# How to send authentication token using curl in golang?

Tags: curl, go

I'm trying to use authentication model to my golang API and I'm using gin framework. I want to send authentication token using curl, then validate it and do all the crud operation after the authentication happens.

My code is like this:

```
func TokenAuthMiddleware() gin.HandlerFunc {
    return func(c *gin.Context) {
        token := c.Request.FormValue("token")

        if token == "" {
            respondWithError(401, "API token required", c)
            return
        }

        if token != os.Getenv("API_TOKEN") {
            respondWithError(401, "Invalid API token", c)
            return
        }

        c.Next()
    }
}

func respondWithError(code int, message string,c *gin.Context) {
    resp := map[string]string{"error": message}

    c.JSON(code, resp)
    c.Abort()
}
```

Main function:

```
func main() {
    router := gin.Default()
    router.Use(TokenAuthMiddleware())
    router.Run(":8000")
}
```

How can I pass the authentication token using curl?

Comment: If you send it as form data you will need to use curl's `--data` flag (read the manual on usage). It would probably make more sense to accept the token in an `Authorization` header.

Answer (score 2):

`c.Request.FormValue("token")` expects that the token is send through a `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` POST request. To accomplish this with cURL you can do something as following:

```
$ curl -i --data "token=<token>" https://example.org/endpoint
```

The downside of this method is that for every request, your `POST` request must contain a token value - but what if you want to use a `GET` or `DELETE` request?

Like @elithrar said, it would make more sense to send the authentication token with an `Authorization` header. Sending the authentication token in the header via cURL is quite easy, use the `-H` flag, e.g.

```
$ curl -i POST -H "Authorization: Bearer <token>" --data "key1=value1&key2=value2" https://example.org
```

A proper way of signing your authentication token is by using [JWT](https://jwt.io/introduction/). I would recommend [`dgrijalva/jwt-go`](https://github.com/dgrijalva/jwt-go) for using JWT.

If you only require one user to access your API, there's no real need for JWT though. Just make sure your authentication token are (pseudo-)randomly generated, e.g. with the `openssl` library:

```
$ openssl rand -out $GOPATH/bin/token.key -base64 128
```

Comment: I used curl -X --data "token=API_TOKEN" `https://example.org/endpoint` but i got {"error":"Invalid API token"}

Comment: My fault - do not use option -X. Are you sure the API_TOKEN matches what is defined in `os.Getenv`? If not, verify why `os.GetEnv` does not match. Otherwise, try sending it via header, and handle it with gin like so: `var token = c.Request.Header.Get("Authorization")`

Comment: thanx but I'm getting same result

Comment: guys any other suggestion if you have please let me know

Comment: Have you tried to pass the token via the `Authorization` header? And handled it appropriately in your Go code?

Comment: yes i tried i you have some examples that will be very helpful thanx

Comment: this is how i do that `token := c.Request.Header.Get("Authorization")` in the terminal ` curl -H "Authorization: Bearer API_TOKEN" -X GET http://localhost:8000/test
` and also tried `curl --data "token=API_TOKEN" -X GET http://localhost:8000/test`

Comment: And `os.Getenv` returns a value as well? Also, when using the `Authorization` header, you don't have to use `Bearer` before the API token per se. It is just the standard of OAuth2: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc6750.